Parent pid dismatch in Minix2
I faced the following problem. I need to write a system call in the Minix2(minix204) operating system that would return the pid of the process with the biggest number of children. I managed to write the call function, but I ran into problems during the testing phase. I tried to test with fork(), created 6 processes, but for some reason they always got a parent pid different from the process where they were created. Regardless of what pid has the process from which they were launched, all of them get parant pid 12. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, I'll attach screenshots and code (the code was scanned from the screenshots, I tried to fix all the typos, but they are possible. The initial code is compiles and run.) of the output(it contains information about all process with IN_USE flag, main proces and pids of children), the code of the test function, and the code of the function that implements the system call.I tried adding a delay in the main process before the call, but that didn't work. I hope for your support, because I have run out of ideas. Minix runs on VMware workstation 17 player. Thanks. output, test function1, test function2, syscall function1, syscall function2   output:
# ./test1
pr:0 children: 4 Father: 0
pr:0 children:3 Father: 0
pr:1 children: 0 Father: 0
pr:3 children: 1 Father: 2
pr:13 children: 0 Father: 3
pr:0 children: 1 Father: 0
pr:19 children: 0 Father: 4
pr:20 children: 0 Father: 4
pr:21 children: 0 Father: 4
pr:22 children: 0 Father: 4
pr:23 children: 0 Father: 4
pr:25 children: 0 Father: 4
pr:26 children: 0 Father: 11
pr:27 children: 0 Father: 12
pr:28 children: 0 Father: 12
pr:29 children: 0 Father: 12
pr:30 children: 0 Father: 12
pr:31 children: 0 Father: 12
pr:32 children: 0 Father: 12
PID of process with biggest number of children: 0 Number of children: 4
Test proces: 26
Children:27, 28, 28, 29, 30, 31
#

test function:
#include <lib.h>
#include <minix/callnr.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    Message m;
    int answ;
    pid_t prid;
    pid_t proc1, proc2, proc3, proc4, proc5, proc6;
    int children;

    proc1 = fork();
    if (proc1 == 0) {
        proc2 = fork();
    }
    if (proc1 == 0 && proc2 != 0) {
        proc3 = fork();
    }
    if (proc1 == 0 && proc2 != 0 && proc3 != 0) {
        proc4 = fork();
    }
    if (proc1 != 0 && proc2 != 0 && proc3 != 0 && proc4 != 0) {
        proc5 = fork();
    }
    if (proc1 == 0 && proc2 != 0 && proc3 != 0 && proc4 != 0 && proc5 != 0) {
        proc6 = fork();
    }

    if (proc1 == 0) {
        sleep(3);
    } else if (proc2 == 0) {
        sleep(3);
    } else if (proc3 == 0) {
        sleep(3);
    } else if (proc4 == 0) {
        sleep(3);
    } else if (proc5 == 0) {
        sleep(3);
    } else if (proc6 == 0) {
        sleep(3);
    } else {
        answ = _syscall(MM, NEW_SYSCALL, &m);
        prid = m.m1_i1;
        children = m.m1_i2;
        printf("PID of process with biggest number of children: %d\n", prid);
        printf("Number of children: %d\n", children);
        printf("Test process: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Children: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", proc1, proc2, proc3, proc4, proc5, proc6);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}

syscall function:
PUBLIC int do_newsyscall(void) {
    int children = 0;
    pid_t prid;
    struct mproc *proc;
    struct mproc *child;

    for (proc = mproc; proc < &mproc[NR_PROCS]; proc++) {
        if (proc->mp_flags & IN_USE) {
            int child_count = 0;
            for (child = mproc; child < &mproc[NR_PROCS]; child++) {
                if ((child->mp_flags & IN_USE) && child->mp_parent == proc->mp_pid) {
                    child_count++;
                }
            }
            if (child_count > children) {
                children = child_count;
                prid = proc->mp_pid;
            }
            printf("pr:%d", proc->mp_pid);
            printf(" children: %d Father: %d\n", child_count, proc->mp_parent);
        }
    }

    mproc[MM_in.M_source].mp_reply.m1_i1 = prid;
    mproc[MM_in.M_source].mp_reply.m1_i2 = children;
    return 1;
}


I don't know anything about internal MINIX kernel structures, but from the behavior of your code, it looks like the mp_parent member of struct mproc holds something other than a PID.  Maybe an index into the process table instead?

@JohnBollinger Holly cow, man you are freaking genius, I've looked on this member several times in mproc.h several times, there was even a comment that it was an index, but for some reason, I just was gazing on it and nothing clicked in my head. Damn i was so close. Thank you so much, I will pray for your well being for the rest of my life!

Problem was in syscall function as @JhonBollinger noticed mp_parent is index of parent in mproc. So it should be
if ((child->mp_flags & IN_USE) && mproc[child->mp_parent].mp_pid == proc->mp_pid) {
                child_count++;
            }

